# Is there a way to solve Gradle sync failed: startup failed: when using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I read a tutorial in the internet how to share preferences in Android studio. I'm getting the error

```
Gradle sync failed: startup failed:
    build file 'D:\praktikum\build.gradle': 11: unexpected 
token: com.android.volley:1.1.0 @ line 11, column 24.
    Implementation 'com.android.volley:1.1.0'
```

and

```
  NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model 
  version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN
```

First I have changed it from `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'` to `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`, but still get error

Here's my gradle top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()

   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()
       jcenter()

     }
  }

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: Check this comment in your code `NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here;` . Therefore you should not add the Volley import in that place.

Comment: hehe i solve it , put it on wrong gradle

Comment: sorrryy but thank your for your time :) @Enzokie

Comment: Your welcome! I am glad it is now working :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare this dependency in module level gradle file..

As you can see clearly in your code..

```
 // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
 // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Module:app level build.gradle

Remove from Project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

```
Implementation 'com.android.volley:1.1.0'
```

add this dependency in your `build.gradle (Module: app)`

and remove from here

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    X implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
```